# minimum texture image dimension for effective classification

Tags: image-processing

Iam a beginner in image mining. I would like to know the minimum dimension required for effective classification of textured images. As what i feel if a image is too small feature extraction step will not extract enough features. And if the image size goes beyond a certain dimension the processing time will increase exponentially with image size.

Comment: It depends on what texture you want to create.
The minimum dimension is 3x3 px
I think the best is 40x40 px
And a bit large but also ok is 400x400px
--
Important
If you use 40x40 px or 100x1 px will always depend on the type of texture, thats why there is no fixed minimum dimension required for effective classification of textured images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complex question that requires a bit of thinking.

**Short answer**: It depends.

**Long answer**: It depends on the type of texture you want to classify and the type of feature your classification is based on. If the feature extracted is, say, color only, you can use "texture" as small as 1x1 pixel (in that case, using the word "texture" is a bit of an abuse). If you want to classify, say for example characters, you can usually extract a lot of local information from edges ([Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform), [Gabor filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter), etc). The image plane just have to be big enough to hold the characters (say 16x16 pixels for [Latin alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_alphabet)).

If you want to be able to classify any kind of images in any kind of number, you can also base your classification on global information, like [entropy](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/entropy.html), [correlogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlogram), energy, inertia, [cluster shade](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.100.8806&rep=rep1&type=pdf), [cluster prominence](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/INF4300/h08/undervisningsmateriale/glcm.pdf), color and [correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence). Those features are used for [content based image retrieval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-based_image_retrieval).

From the top of my head, I would try using texture as small as 32x32 pixels if the kind of texture you are using is *a priori* unknown. If on the contrary the kind of texture is *a priori* known, I would choose one or more feature that I know would classify the images according to my needs (1x1 pixel for color-only, 16x16 pixels for characters, etc). Again, it really depends on what you are trying to achieve. There isn't a unique answer to your question.